# Edge.js with newer versions of .NET ( 6 && 7 )

Tags: .net, edge.js

How can I use Edge.js with .NET version 6.0 ( or 7.0 ) and Node.js version v16.18.0?

After installing Edge.js using nuget ( `dotnet add package EdgeJs --version 11.15.0` ) and importing it into my .csproj (   ) I wanna use it ( using EdgeJs; || using Edge ) but getting an error:

> The type or namespace name 'EdgeJs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to use EdgeJS to call .NET 6/7 from JavaScript running under node.  I don't think you can go the other way.

Answer (score 6):

The [original Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) by Tomasz Tjanczuk was last updated in 2017 and doesn't support the latest versions of .NET.  It will still work in a .NET Framework app on Windows, and the [inline code in the original documentation to call from C# into JavaScript](https://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/48) still works in such an application. The [latest version is 8.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Edge.js/).

There is a [fork of the original project](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js) which is maintained and DOES support .NET 6.0.  However, for .NET 6.0 and later [you cannot call from C# into JavaScript using this project](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js/issues/145) I think.  The only direction of travel is to call from JavaScript to C# (and back to JavaScript).  This doesn't need the NuGet package, just the npm package.

I got calls working from JavaScript to .NET 7.0 using the forked npm package and node.js 16.18.0 on Windows.  The steps to do this are below:

- Ensure [node 16.18.0](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.18.0/) is installed
- Create a folder and create a C# .NET 7.0 class library project called 'QuickStart.NET7' in it.
- Add a class called LocalMethods with the code below, which is taken from the [quick start code for the forked project](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js-quick-start).  You can delete any other existing class (Class1.cs):

```
    namespace QuickStart.NET7
    {
        public class LocalMethods
        {
            public async Task<object> UseDynamicInput(dynamic input)
            {
                return $".NET 7 welcomes {input}";
            }
        }
    }
```

- Do a debug build of the .NET class library
- Open a command prompt/terminal in your folder and do `npm i edge-js@19.3.0`
- Create a text file called main.js in the same folder, and paste the code below into it:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const baseDll = path.join(__dirname, 'QuickStart.NET7/QuickStart.NET7/bin/Debug/net7.0/QuickStart.NET7.dll');
    const localTypeName = 'QuickStart.NET7.LocalMethods';
    console.log('Base DLL:'+ baseDll);
    process.env.EDGE_USE_CORECLR = 1;
    const edge = require('edge-js');
    const useDynamicInput = edge.func({
        assemblyFile: baseDll,
        typeName: localTypeName,
        methodName: 'UseDynamicInput'
    });
    useDynamicInput('Node.Js', function(error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(result);
    });
```

- Do `node main.js` in the command prompt/terminal

You should get output, coming from the C# function, of '.NET 7 welcomes Node.Js'.  If you get a 'Could not load file or assembly' error check the Base DLL path is correct.

The same code as above works for .NET 6 as well.  I have only tested this works on Windows, but the readme suggests it should work on Linux and MacOS for .NET 6.